# Why does a client-side exception occur when deploying nextjs13 to vercel?

Tags: vercel, next.js13, react-query, supabase

I created a project with nextjs version 13.4.2, supabase, and react-query and am hosting it with vercel. Page ssr that receives data from the server?

This error appears in the console:

> Error: Connection closed.
> Uncaught (in promise) Error: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received

This message appears on the page:

> Application error: a client-side exception has occurred (see the browser console for more information).

Data patching sites such as login or membership registration and routing to Link work normally, but if you refresh or access the ssr page from the beginning, an error will occur.

Why does something like that happen? How to solve this? I would appreciate your help. Please understand that the sentences are awkward because I used a translator.

I deployed next.js13 to vercel, but the error `Application error: a client-side exception has occurred (see the browser console for more information).` occurs on the ssr and csr pages.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.